# Data Not Correctly Importing When Using SQLite3 in Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to use the following to import some data from an SQLite3 databse.

```
def ImportStudents():
    conn = sqlite3.connect(r"E:\COMP4\Languages")
    c = conn.cursor()
    count = 0
    i = (count)
    var = c.execute('SELECT * FROM Students WHERE StudentID = ?', str(i))
    return var
```

It is not generating any syntax errors but instead of returning a name, it is returning this:

```
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x02E1E620>
```

I have tried playing around with it but everything I do either generates a syntax error or gives the same output and I have been unable to find help elsewhere. Can anyone else see why this isn't working.

Comment: When I say returning I mean that that is what is being printed as the value for var

Comment: Try this and see what it prints: `for row in var:
        print row `

Comment: Whereabouts do I need to put that?

Comment: after `var = c.execute('SELECT * FROM Students WHERE StudentID = ?', str(i))`

Comment: Did you try taking a look at the exmaples in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)?

Comment: you need to add one of the `fetch` functions, like fetchone or fetchall. You can put that right after execute, or separately on the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

You do not get the results from sqlite directly - the API can't possibly know if the result of your query is a single value, a row of values, or even multiple rows.

Thus it will always return a cursor, and it is your responsibility to handle that.

In your case, a

```
 return var.fetchone()
```

is probably what you want.